# Can using glasses with a positive prescription when using a computer help prevent or minimize myopia?

Tags: eye, computers, vision, opthalmology

I've seen multiple sources linking screen-time on a computer and myopia. If this is correct that exerting our eye-muscles causes this, would using glasses with a positive prescription prevent that?

What I mean is, if someone who uses -5.00 glasses, uses -4.00 glasses for their computer. That would be like someone who has perfect vision and uses +1.00 glasses for the computer.

The best source I've seen is https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31943280/ which already points out that the connection between screen-time and myopia is not clear (pun unintended). But my question is not about whether the connection is there or not. My question is about whether assuming they are connected, would using positive numbered glasses be logical. It seems logical to me. But I have never heard of this being advised by optometrists/ophthalmologists to anyone.

Comment: Hi and welcome! If you have perfect (near) vision, using +1 dioptre lens will cause blurring. This might not be primarily the optics, but the strain on the eye muscles that move the eyes to focus on a near object.

Comment: @Chris It does not if looking at something close. It does if looking at something far.

Comment: I suppose a low power lens could reduce the distance to your near point, like in a near-eye display.

Comment: There are contact lenses that, according to the literature, are supposed to [slow progression of myopia](https://www.nih.gov/news-events/news-releases/multifocal-contact-lenses-slow-myopia-progression-children), but I don't know for glasses. You best bet would be to talk to an optometrist/optician.